# Is it possible to encode and decode a big text?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say somebody is writing some confidential information to MySQL through `textarea`.

Can I somehow encode this text with PHP help and put it to MySQL. But later, when I will need this text to be shown, I will have to decode it and people will see it as normal text.

Is it possible to do that, so if hacker steals my database, he won't be able to see what other person wrote?

Comment: Thank you, now I am going to delete my question knowing that.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to ask how you might go about that? What have you considered?

Comment: you can use encyrption for fields of your database, a simple google search will give you intersting results. You can do it in pure application levels or use some functions from the databases engines.

Comment: If it’s confidential information, you should not just encode it but encrypt it.

Comment: @Gumbo♦: and what should I do?

Comment: @hey: You probably meant the right thing but just used the wrong term. Because encoded data does not require a key to be decoded whereas encryption does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set an encryption key:

```
$key = 'yourpasswordhere';
$string = ' confidential information here '; // note the spaces
```

Encrypt it on DB entry:

```
$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
var_dump($encrypted); // "ey7zu5zBqJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp+KSNR4/GAv14w="
```

Decrypt it later:

```
$decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
var_dump($decrypted); // " confidential information here "
```